# how to find missing Dates for given ranges

Tags: mysql-workbench

How to query in mysql to find missing date from table

I have table like

uid     date        hours

4       06/07/2014  8:00

5       07/07/2014  6:00

6       11/07/2014  8:00

7       13/07/2014  7:00

I need to get missed dates like

08/07/2014
09/07/2014
10/07/2014
12/07/2014

please help me anyone...

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522701/how-to-find-missing-rows-dates-in-a-mysql-table. please check this