# How to find missing data in table Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is similar to [How to find missing data rows using SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852293/how-to-find-missing-data-rows-using-sql) and [How to find missing rows (dates) in a mysql table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522701/how-to-find-missing-rows-dates-in-a-mysql-table) but a bit more complex, so I'm hitting a wall.

I have a data table with the noted Primary key:

```
country_id (PK)
product_id (PK)
history_date (PK)
amount
```

I have a products table with all products, a countries table, and a calendar table with all valid dates.

I'd like to find all countries, dates and products for which there are missing products, with this wrinkle:
I only care about dates for which there are entries for a country for at least one product (i.e. if the country has NOTHING on that day, I don't need to find it) - so, by definition, there is an entry in the history table for every country and date I care about.

I know it's going to involve some joins maybe a cross join, but I'm hitting a real wall in finding missing data.

I tried this (pretty sure it wouldn't work):

```
SELECT h.history_date, h.product_id, h.country_id, h.amount
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN history h ON (p.product_id = h.product_id)
WHERE h.product_id IS NULL
```

No Joy.

I tried this too:

```
WITH allData AS (SELECT h1.country_id, p.product_id, h1.history_date
FROM products p 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT country_id, history_date FROM history) h1)
SELECT f.history_date, f.product_id, f.country_id
FROM allData f
LEFT OUTER JOIN history h ON (f.country_id = h.country_id AND f.history_date = h.history_date AND f.product_id = h.product_id)
WHERE h.product_id IS NULL 
   AND h.country_id IS NOT NULL 
   AND h.history_date IS NOT null
```

also no luck.  The CTE does get me every product on every date that there is also data, but the rest returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only care about dates for which there are entries for a country for
> at least one product (i.e. if the country has NOTHING on that day, I
> don't need to find it)

So we care about this combination:

```
from    (select distinct country_id, history_date from history) country_date
cross join products p
```

Then it's just a matter of checking for existence:

```
select *
from    (select distinct country_id, history_date from history) country_date
cross join products p
where not exists (select null
                  from history h
                  where country_date.country_id   = h.country_id
                   and  country_date.history_date = h.history_date
                   and  p.product_id              = h.product_id
                 )
```

Comment: So I was close, but no cigar.  This is great, thanks!

Comment: To correct your version, you just need to look at the filters you are using against your outer joined table. `AND h.country_id IS NOT NULL ` is only going to be true if there is a row matched on all of the outer join conditions.